# getting the vagrant command line arguments inside the Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant

I have the following configuration that only makes sense for vagrant up command:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = false
  if ENV["VB_GUI"] == "true" then vb.gui = true
  else
     puts("[info] VB_GUI environment variable not set so running headless")
  end
end
```

Is it possible to hook into the vagrant API to retrieve the command currently being executed? E.g.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = false
  if VAGRANT_API.command == "up"  # how can I do this?
    if ENV["VB_GUI"] == "true" then vb.gui = true
    else
       puts("[info] VB_GUI environment variable not set so running headless")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `Vagrantfile` is just ruby code so you can easily get the command line arguments using the `ARGV` array.

Take the following vagrant command for example:

`vagrant up webserver`

That would start the Vagrant box defined as webserver in your `Vagrantfile`. You can then access the arguments like so:

```
ARGV[0] = up
ARGV[1] = webserver
```

So using your example you need to do the following:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = false
  if ARGV[0] == "up"
    if ENV["VB_GUI"] == "true" then vb.gui = true
    else
       puts("[info] VB_GUI environment variable not set so running headless")
    end
  end
end
```