# Finding current vagrant operation from inside Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm looking for a way to find the current "vagrant" sub-command (e.g. "up", "provision") from inside the Vagrantfile.

I know about being able to fetch ARGV (e.g. [getting the vagrant command line arguments inside the Vagrantfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867369/getting-the-vagrant-command-line-arguments-inside-the-vagrantfile)), but a simple lookup for "up" and "provision" in ARGV could accidentally pick up plugin sub-command arguments.

Is there a way to tell from inside the Vagrantfile which command Vagrant is intending to execute?

The motivation is to avoid executing time-consuming operations which are required for "provision" and "up" but redundant for other sub-commands (e.g. fetching information from AWS).

Comment: What are you using for provisioning?

Comment: @user2182349 I use a mix of Puppet and shell scripts to provision. I want to query S3 bucket objects but only if I'm going to provision. I want to avoid slowing down other commands (like "status"/"destroy"/"ssh"/"halt" etc) when I don't need this information.

Comment: Could you post the Vagrantfile?

Comment: @user2182349 It contains too much information I'd rather not expose, and I'm not sure how this is related to my question.

Comment: Can you move all the provisioning out of the up?