# Vagrant: delete synced folder on host with `vagrant destroy`

Tags: vagrant

I'm using vagrant to stand up some development environments. I have vagrant create a synced folder on the host machine. I have chef git-clone a project into the corresponding folder on the guest machine. This project then obviously appears in the synced folder on the host machine. All good...

However, if I need to destroy the vagrant instance, the synced folder and project still exists on the host machine. I find it best to delete this folder before I `vagrant up` again to avoid unexpectedly altering the freshly cloned project. Of course, I often forget to do this and it wastes a lot of time.

My question:
Can and how do I configure vagrant to delete the synced folder on the host machine when I execute `vagrant up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vagrantfile` is basically a piece of Ruby code, so you can put a quite complicated logic there. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892216/471899) shows how command line arguments can be obtained in the file so you can execute some deletion actions only during `vagrant up` process.

But I would recommend you to install [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin and use it.

Comment: The vagrant-triggers plugin is perfect! Thank you!